# ¿Cómo eliminar el fondo en las imágenes usando intervention image?

Tags: php, imagen, intervention

Estoy intentando eliminar el fondo blanco de los logotipos para obtener un icono transparente, por ejemplo

en esta imagen

[image]

Es .jpg, quiero eliminar el fondo blanco (solo lo que está afuera si es posible, de lo contrario eliminar todo el fondo blanco)

Estoy tratando de usar laravel [intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) con este código

```
public function resizeImage($logo, $placeName, $domain)
{
    $mask = Image::make($logo)
        ->contrast(100)
        ->contrast(50)
        ->trim('top-left', null, 40)
        ->invert(); // invert it to use as a mask

    $new_image = Image::canvas($mask->width(), $mask->height(), '#000000')
        ->mask($mask)
        ->resize(32,32, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        })
        ->encode('png', 100);

    $route = $domain . '/favicon/favicon.png';

    Storage::disk('gcs')
        ->put($route, $new_image);
    $route = Storage::disk('gcs')
        ->url($route);

    return $route;
}
```

pero el resultado es el siguiente

[image]

la imagen pierde color, se vuelve negra

qué estoy haciendo mal? veo que la imagen se vuelve así a partir del uso de ->mask, sin embargo si intento utilizar otro método para colocar la imagen obtengo un ícono totalmente negro

Comment: No se absolutamente nada de esto, pero pediría un pequeño cambio a probar. Estás aplicando una mascara `#000000`, el cual es de color negro. Pintala de color rojo `#ff0000` y dime que resultado obtienes.

Comment: @Excorpion Sí, así sale rojo, lo que obviamente no está bien porque estoy trabajando con distintos logos, pero me sirvió de ayuda, al parecer esta manera no es la correcta por el mismo motivo, gracias

Comment: No se si puedas como mencione.. Pero si quitas solo el repintando de la mascara, no funciona ? ... es decir, haces la mascara, pero sin tener que cambiar sus colores... no se si el metodo lo permita

Comment: AL parecer es opcional, pero verifica a ver que resultados obtienes

Comment: @Excorpion sale una imagen totalmente negra, el fondo negro y la máscara ni siquiera es añadida, tendré que buscar otro método ya que por lo visto la máscara necesita de un color

Comment: Entonces quizas no sea el mejor método para lo que buscas...